# In a bootstrap table how remove lines between rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table, I want to remove the lines between some of the rows in the table (at the end of the table) is there a quick way to achieve this?

Comment: Given those rows your own CSS class and then use that class to remove the border?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove the border from Bootstrap tables using the following CSS:

```css
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th {
  border-top: none;
}
```

This will override Bootstrap's `td` and `th` selector [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and apply your `border-top` style instead of theirs.

*Note that this will only apply to `tr` elements within the `tbody`. You'll need to add in styling for the `thead` and `tfoot` elements if you want this to work for those as well.*

Now where you specify ***some*** of the rows, I'm guessing you don't want this applying to all of them. For that, simply add a new `class` to the `tr` elements you wish remove the border on, and include that class name in your CSS selector(s):

```
<tr class="no-border">...</tr>
```

```css
.table>tbody>tr.no-border>td,
.table>tbody>tr.no-border>th {
  border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, I realized I just had to remove table-bordered (bs4)

Answer (score 2):

For the rows in which you don't want border's to appear. Give them an additional **class** and add the **border:none** property to it.

For Ex : If you give the additional class name as **.noborder** to the  element of the row.

Hope this helps you.

```css
.noborder{
border:none;

}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr><td>Data 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data 1</td></tr>
  <tr ><td>Data 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="noborder">Data 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="noborder">Data 1</td></tr>
  
  </table>
```

Comment: Just to make this clearer - add the above to the td within the tr , e.g. <tr> <td colspan="4" class="noborder"></td></tr> , where colspan is how many columns you have in your table. Adding it to the tr WILL NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `border-bottom: none;` in your **right selector**. Please provide your html code so that we can figure out and analyze your structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table class="table no-border">
      <tr>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **react-bootstrap** adding the className `table-borderless` will do the trick.

eg :

```
<Table className="table-borderless"></Table>
```

Answer (score -3):

i think you want to remove two remove vertical line between two row or column 
go through this link to see demo LInk :-  http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

also you can apply 
    .table>tbody>tr.no-border>td,
    .table>tbody>tr.no-border>th {
      border-top: none;
    }